# How can I shrink the UI in Google Chrome back to normal size after an update?

Tags: google-chrome

Everything such as title bar and tap icon and extension icons and setting or another things in Google Chrome was biggest after update it.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome.]

As you can see in this picture, the Chrome extension and bookmark bars and their titles are big.

How do I make all of the UI in the browser controls smaller?

Comment: this is screen shot => http://s8.picofile.com/file/8284422926/chrome.png

Comment: as you can see in this picture chrome extension and bookmark bar and their title , was big .

Answer (score 0):

Look in `about:flags` for something about hybrid (maybe it was touch) or UI.

Click the selection box

Select something else.